# Headless WordPress and React in the same folder/server

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, react-router

I'm trying to use headless WordPress with a React-powered frontend. What I want to achieve is being able to use /wp-admin/, /wp-json/ and such endpoints while still being able to use my site without my react-router picking up on these URIs.

So, when I visit example.com/blog, I reach my React app, which is good.
However, when I visit example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, I still reach my React App which is not good. I kind of want the same behaviour as https://techcrunch.com has.

The problem lies within the .htaccess file, I believe.

So I have my www-folder and moved my build files to that folder (by running npm run build). Inside that folder I also have .htaccess and a folder called 'wp', the wp folder contains my WordPress installation.

I followed these links but can't seem to find the last piece to the puzzle (mainly because I still don't understand how to customize .htaccess properly):

https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-i-without-url-change

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

React is just a JS bundle. You could just copy the index.html to a custom theme folder, rename it index.php, add a style.css, and just copy the other root files to your WordPress directory.

Comment: Mess React compiled HTML with other Wordpress files is a very bad pratice in general.
Don't do it, if you want to keep all clean and right.